# Sketchup Free: Everything else disappears on double clicking a group

Tags: sketchup

For a few days now, when I double click a group (to enter it) everything else disappears.

Nothing double clicked:
[image: Everything is visible]

First floor group double clicked:
[image: Only the first floor is visible]

This happens only on one Project. Other Projects behave as expected: By double clicking a group everything else gets less saturated but stays visible.
What did I do and how can I get the default behaviour back?

Comment: Because it works  on other files and not this one in particular, it sounds to me that it is a document setting that might have got ticked (or un-ticked). I am not familiar with sketchup- free but my CAD program has similar settings (show, grey, or hide others) for different layers, objects, and classes. I assume you tried to save and restart...

Comment: Yes, I tried to restart. I also had the Idea that I might have ticked a setting (possbly by accident with a hotkey) but there is nothing in that regard that I could find in the app settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found it.

1. Click on "Display" on the right ssidebar
2. Uncheck "Hide rest of model"

[image]